# Cleaning Piano Keys

Tags: piano, digital-piano

What should I use to clean my piano keys so that they don't get greasy or sticky? I notice some dust on them but not sure what to use.

Comment: Washing and drying hands prior to playing should ensure no grease or dirt. And of course, always keep away from children... Dust - use a duster.

Comment: How often do people play that piano? The dust makes me think it isn't played that often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always used warm soapy water on a wash cloth, not dripping, for dirt and grease, and then I dry it with a soft towel.  For dust and loose dirt, I use a vacuum cleaner with a dust brush attachment and I focus on the spaces between the keys as well as the tops of the keys. For the piano cabinet I just use a tack cloth to keep it clean.